# What is accents commands behavior ?

Tags: accents

I've read LaTeX sources to define the real behavior of accent commands and I've failed. It states with this:

> ```
> \def\DeclareTextAccent#1#2#3{%  
> \DeclareTextCommand#1{#2}{\add@accent{#3}}}
> ```

i.e. it constructs from `\accent` TeX-primitive.

Then I've went to *TeX by Topic* book and read about `\accent` primitive. But unfortunately I can't find any useful information that will explains the accent's behavior. **I need to know how does x-position and y-position of accent symbols are calculated.**

I've found such info:

> The width of a character with an
>   accent is the same as that of the
>   unaccented character. TeX assumes that
>   the accent as it appears in the font
>   file is properly positioned for a
>   character that is as high as the
>   x-height of the font; for characters
>   with other heights it correspondingly
>   lowers or raises the accent.
>
> ...
>
> The horizontal positioning of an
>   accent is controlled by `\fontdimen1`,
>   slant per point. Kerns are used for
>   the horizontal movement.

But even knowing that I can't find answer to my question. Maybe you can?

Answer (score 2):

I think *The TeXbook* is the place to look here. It says

> Appendix B shows that plain TeX
>   handles most of the accents by using
>   TeX's `\accent` primitive. For
>   example, `\'#1` is equivalent to
>   `{\accent19 #1}`, where `#1` is the
>   argument being accented. The general
>   rule is that `\accent<number>` puts an
>   accent over the next character; the
>   `<number>` tells where that accent
>   appears in the current font. The
>   accent is assumed to be properly
>   positioned for a character whose
>   height equals the x-height of the
>   current font; taller or shorter
>   characters cause the accent to be
>   raised or lowered, taking due account
>   of the slantedness of the fonts of
>   accenter and accentee. The width of
>   the final construction is the width of
>   the character being accented,
>   regardless of the width of the accent.

Thus the position is not calculated by the `\accent` primitive: it's determined by the font designer when the font is designed.

Comment: Hmmm, but as you mentioned:  __The accent is assumed to be properly positioned for a character whose height equals the x-height of the current font; taller or shorter characters cause the accent to be raised or lowered, taking due account of the slantedness of the fonts of accenter and accentee.__  So it is not font business for position accents, e.g. symbol **_** hasn't diacritic analog for it, so accent will be positioned lower than for other symbols and the question is *how lower* ?

Comment: _doing for notification_